# How can I pass data from Angular to Node.Js server and vice versa by one endpoint?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, endpoint

I have code in `Nodejs` as backend and `Angular` as frontend.
I want to receive and send data by one endpoint and based on that data from server toggle a button. Toggling is working now but I want when I sign out from the dashboard next time that I log in I could see the value of the key is based on the value from the database.
For example, first, it's **SET** after clicking it changed to **CLEAR** and I sign out from the dashboard. When next time I log in I want to see the **CLEAR** label on my button.

These are codes for several parts of the app:

**Angular Service**

```
this.setUserFeatured = function(id, setFeatured) {
    return $http.put('/admin/v2/users/' + id + '/featured', { setFeatured: setFeatured })
  .then(returnedDataOrError);
};
```

**Angular Controller**

```
function updateFeaturedButtonLabel() {
  $scope.featuredButtonLabel = $scope.user.setFeatured ? "Clear Featured" : "Set Featured";
}

function toggleFeatured () {
  $scope.user.setFeatured = !$scope.user.setFeatured;
  UserService.setUserFeatured($stateParams.id, $scope.user.setFeatured)
  updateFeaturedButtonLabel();
};
```

**Html File**

```
<a class="btn btn-info" ng-click="toggleFeatured()" ng-class="{on:user.setFeatured}">{{featuredButtonLabel}}</a>
```

**Server Controller**

```
function addFeaturedUser(req: $Request, res: $Response, next: NextFunction) {
  const schema = Joi.object().keys(_.pick(validate, ['userId', 'setFeatured']));
  const queryParams = { userId: req.params.id };
 if (!req.params.id) {
  return new errors.BadRequest('userId is not specified');
 }

 return validate.validate(queryParams, schema)
  .then(validatedParams =>
    userService5.updateUserLabel(validatedParams.userId, req.body.setFeatured))
  .then(result => res.json(result))
  .catch(next);
 }


router.put('/users/:id/featured', addFeaturedUser);
```

And **`updateUserLabel`** is a function that handling the connection to the database and retrieving the data.

I just wonder how can I use the data from the server to change the label of the button?

`true/false` for the setting the button is coming from the `.then(result => res.json(result))`

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Once you logout you loose session information. You need to maintain that state even after you logout. What you can do is use $localstorage and once you make your button 'CLEAR' set some state variable in localstorage, and next time when you come to dashboard read this variable from localstorage and set your 'CLEAR' text.

Answer (score 0):

For your question, I suppose you are asking how to use the `response` object returned in

```
$http.put().then(function(response){})
```

You can find the structure of response object in following document.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

[image]

To access the data returned from server:

```
$http.put().then(function(response){response.data})
```

which corresponds to what your server sends.

Besides, the `toggleFeatured` function should be add to `$scope` object.
Otherwise, `ng-click` can't trigger that function in html template.

Hope it helps.